# How to filter data of a html-table with a drop-down-menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a html-file which makes a table with 3 columns and dynamic rows. The data for the table will be read in from a java project. The java project doesn't matter here.
I also did a drop-down-menu on my table for the first column with two entries. Now I would like to filter my table when I choose one entry of the drop-down-menu. How can i do that? How do I need to use JavaScript here?

See the code below (only html because I don't know what to do in Javascript)

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col width="150" style="background-color:red"></col>
        <col width="165"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tr  style ="background-color:grey">
        <th>
            Plane
            <select size="2" name="choice">
                <option selected="selected">number_1</option>
                <option>number_2</option>                       
            </select>                   
        </th>   
        <th>date</th>
        <th>addition</th>
    </tr>


    <xsl:for-each select="logstore/plane/trigger">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../name"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="date"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="addition"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: That's not valid html...

Comment: You would need to attach an `onchange event` to your drop down, then either do some hide and show magic for rows in your table, or send an `ajax` request to the server to return only results that match your filter and re-populate your table body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

(adapted from [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp), with the `input` element replaced by a [`select` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) and the `onkeyup` attribute replaced by [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) -- See comments in the code for further explanation of how it works)

```js
function filterTable() {
  // Variables
  let dropdown, table, rows, cells, country, filter;
  dropdown = document.getElementById("countriesDropdown");
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  filter = dropdown.value;

  // Loops through rows and hides those with countries that don't match the filter
  for (let row of rows) { // `for...of` loops through the NodeList
    cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");
    country = cells[1] || null; // gets the 2nd `td` or nothing
    // if the filter is set to 'All', or this is the header row, or 2nd `td` text matches filter
    if (filter === "All" || !country || (filter === country.textContent)) {
      row.style.display = ""; // shows this row
    }
    else {
      row.style.display = "none"; // hides this row
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="countriesDropdown" oninput="filterTable()">
  <option>All</option>
  <option>Sweden</option>
  <option>Germany</option>
</select>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Country</th></tr><!-- header row uses 'th' instead of 'td' -->
  <tr><td>Inga</td><td>Sweden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Helena</td><td>Sweden</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hans</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Anna</td><td>Germany</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks cat but that code is not working until you use "onchange" instead of "oninput" because "oninput" will not work in <select>, so "onchange" does. You also need to have a reference to your JavaScript file with `<script type="text/javascript" src="/../../filterTable.js"></script>`

Comment: It seems to work fine in the snippet. No external file is necessary to run a script on an html page, but referencing an external file is a good idea to keep your programming separate from your markup. Even better would be to remove the `oninput` (or `onchange`) attribute and handle that part in the JS code with `document.getElementById("countriesDropdown").addEventListener("change","filterTable");` I'm glad you found something that works for you.